# Spiral matrix diagonal element sum

Tags: c++, algorithm, aptitude

Let `n=5`, then for matrix

```
1  2  3  4  5
16 17 18 19 6
15 24 25 20 7
14 23 22 21 8 
13 12 11 10 9
```

then sum of diagonal elements is:

```
=1+17+25+21+9+5+19+23+13
```

Sum for `n=15`?

One way is to make the spiral matrix and then by a loop, we get the answer, but its time and space complexity is large.

Like this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-diagonals-spiral-odd-order-square-matrix/
but the problem here starts 1 from the center.

Comment: If they start from the center, you can see it as being a similar problem, the value `M(i,j)` in a matrix starting from center being `n² - M(i,j)` in the matrix starting from an extremity point.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the outer "shell" of the matrix. The sum of the values at the four vertices, given a size of **n** (5 in your example) and a starting value of **s** (1 in your example) is

s + (s + (n-1)) + (s + (n-1)*2) + (s + (n-1)*3) = 4*s + (n - 1)*6

The same applies to the inner values, once updated **n** and **s**:

s = s + 4 * (n - 1)
n = n - 2

If **n** becomes less then 2, well, either we have the central element or nothing (**n** is even).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Bob_'s answer, Here is a recursive code in CPP as requested by OP

```
int shellcalc(int n,int s){
    if(n==1)
        return s;
    else if(n==0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        int sum=4*s+(n-1)*6;
        int snew=s+4*(n-1);
        int nnew=n-2;
        return sum+shellcalc(nnew,snew);
    }
}
```

try it out here https://rextester.com/FLJD46264 
Python - https://rextester.com/MDMV32855